# Typescript enum - use keys to define type

Tags: typescript, enums

My question is kinda simple, but even if there are some answers, none was working for me. I have string Enum:

```
enum EventTypeEnum {
  TYPE_ONE = "Type 1",
  TYPE_TWO = "Type 2",
  TYPE_THREE = "Type 3"
};
```

and I have type defining the response from API, from what I get the type of the object:

```
type EventResponseType = {
  event_id: string;
  event_type: "TYPE_ONE" | "TYPE_TWO" | "TYPE_THREE";
};
```

I think you understand what I need immediately from this snippet, but further to explanation. From API I get type of the object, but in UI it should have another value/label, so I defined the enum to this purpose. Then I have another type used for UI object:

```
type EventType = EventResponseType & {
  event_type_text: EventTypeEnum;
};
```

Now I can use it this way:

```
const loadEvent = (eventResponse: EventResponseType): EventType => {
  return {
    ...eventResponse,
    ...{ event_type_text: EventTypeEnum[eventResponse.event_type] }
  };
}
```

So, my question is if there is a way how to use enum to define `event_type` in `EventResponseType` instead of listing it using strings. So instead of:

```
event_type: "TYPE_ONE" | "TYPE_TWO" | "TYPE_THREE";
```

I am looking for something like:

```
event_type: Object.keys(EventTypeEnum);
```

=> but this is not working obviously.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you're directly using `EventTypeEnum` to define a string union type. You will need ***[`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)*** and ***[`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator)*** in conjunction to achieve your result. Something like:

```js
// Your event type enum
type keysForEnum = keyof typeof EventTypeEnum;
type EventResponseType = {
  event_id: string;
  event_type: keysForEnum;
};

// Something like:
const loadEvent = (eventResponse: EventResponseType): EventType => {
  return {
    ...eventResponse,
    event_type_text: EventTypeEnum[eventResponse.event_type as keysForEnum]
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi @mandy8055, thank you very much, this seemed very promising, but still I'm getting an error. Here `EventTypeEnum[eventResponse.event_type as keysForEnum]` I am getting:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"TYPE_ONE" | "TYPE_TWO" | "TYPE_THREE"' can't be used to index type 'typeof EventTypeEnum'. Property 'TYPE_ONE' does not exist on type 'typeof EventTypeEnum'. Any idea here? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote me the following helper function

```
export function getKeyString<T>(types: Dictionary<unknown>, enumValue: T): string | undefined {
  return Object
    .entries(types)
    .filter(([key]) => isNaN(Number(key)))
    .find(([, value]) => value === enumValue)?.[0];
}
```

how to use it:

```
const enumString: string = getKeyString(EventTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum. TYPE_ONE);
```

Is it what you asked for?

The dictionary is defined as

```
export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas Renger, thank you for your answer, but I mean something different. mandy8055's answer looks good.